# Unable to join Akka.NET cluster

Tags: akka.net, akka.net-cluster, akka.net-networking

I am having a problem joining and debugging joining to Akka.NET cluster. I am using version 1.3.8. My setup is following:

### Lighthouse

Almost default code from github. Runs in console akka.hocon is following:

```
lighthouse {
  actorsystem: "sng"
}

petabridge.cmd{
    host = "0.0.0.0"
    port = 9110
}

akka {
  loglevel = DEBUG
  loggers = ["Akka.Logger.Serilog.SerilogLogger, Akka.Logger.Serilog"]
  actor {
    provider = "Akka.Cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider, Akka.Cluster"
                  debug {
                  receive = on
                  autoreceive = on
                  lifecycle = on
                  event-stream = on
                  unhandled = on
              }
  }
  remote {
      log-sent-messages = on
      log-received-messages = on
      log-remote-lifecycle-events = on
        enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.dot-netty.tcp"]
    dot-netty.tcp {
      transport-class = "Akka.Remote.Transport.DotNetty.TcpTransport, Akka.Remote"
      applied-adapters = []
      transport-protocol = tcp
      hostname = "0.0.0.0"
      port = 4053
    }
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = DEBUG
  }            
  cluster {
    auto-down-unreachable-after = 5s
    seed-nodes = [] 
    roles = [lighthouse]
  }
}
```

### Working node

Also console (net461) application with as simple as possible startup and joining. It works as excpected. akka.hocon:

```
akka {
  loglevel = DEBUG
  loggers = ["Akka.Logger.Serilog.SerilogLogger, Akka.Logger.Serilog"]
  actor {
    provider = "Akka.Cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider, Akka.Cluster"
  }

  remote {
      log-sent-messages = on
      log-received-messages = on
      log-remote-lifecycle-events = on
    dot-netty.tcp {
      transport-class = "Akka.Remote.Transport.DotNetty.TcpTransport, Akka.Remote"
      applied-adapters = []
      transport-protocol = tcp
      hostname = "0.0.0.0"
      port = 0
    }
  }            

  cluster {
    auto-down-unreachable-after = 5s
    seed-nodes = ["akka.tcp://sng@127.0.0.1:4053"] 
    roles = [monitor]
  }
}
```

### Not working node

An .NET 4.6.1 library, registerd as COM and started in other (Media Monkey) application with VBA code:

```
Sub OnStartup
   Set o = CreateObject("MediaMonkey.Akka.Agent.MediaMonkeyAkkaProxy")
   o.Init(SDB)
End Sub
```

Akka system is, as in console aplikation, created with standard `ActorSystem.Create("sng", config);`

akka.hocon:

```
akka {
  loglevel = DEBUG
  loggers = ["Akka.Logger.Serilog.SerilogLogger, Akka.Logger.Serilog"]
  actor {
    provider = "Akka.Cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider, Akka.Cluster"
  }
  remote {
      log-sent-messages = on
      log-received-messages = on
      log-remote-lifecycle-events = on
    dot-netty.tcp {
      transport-class = "Akka.Remote.Transport.DotNetty.TcpTransport, Akka.Remote"
      applied-adapters = []
      transport-protocol = tcp
      hostname = "0.0.0.0"
      port = 0
    }
  }            
  cluster {
    auto-down-unreachable-after = 5s
    seed-nodes = ["akka.tcp://sng@127.0.0.1:4053"] 
    roles = [mediamonkey]
  }
}
```

### Debugging workflow

1. Startup Lighthouse application:

   Configuration Result:
   [Success] Name sng.Lighthouse
   [Success] ServiceName sng.Lighthouse
   Topshelf v4.0.0.0, .NET Framework v4.0.30319.42000
   [Lighthouse] ActorSystem: sng; IP: 127.0.0.1; PORT: 4053
   [Lighthouse] Performing pre-boot sanity check. Should be able to parse address [akka.tcp://sng@127.0.0.1:4053]
   [Lighthouse] Parse successful.
   [21:01:35 INF] Starting remoting
   [21:01:35 INF] Remoting started; listening on addresses : [akka.tcp://sng@127.0.0.1:4053]
   [21:01:35 INF] Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://sng@127.0.0.1:4053]
   [21:01:35 INF] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://sng@127.0.0.1:4053] - Starting up...
   [21:01:35 INF] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://sng@127.0.0.1:4053] - Started up successfully
   The sng.Lighthouse service is now running, press Control+C to exit.
   [21:01:35 INF] petabridge.cmd host bound to [0.0.0.0:9110]
   [21:01:35 INF] Node [akka.tcp://sng@127.0.0.1:4053] is JOINING, roles [lighthouse]
   [21:01:35 INF] Leader is moving node [akka.tcp://sng@127.0.0.1:4053] to [Up]
2. Started and stopped working console node

Lighthouse logs:

```
[21:05:40 INF] Node [akka.tcp://sng@0.0.0.0:37516] is JOINING, roles [monitor]
[21:05:40 INF] Leader is moving node [akka.tcp://sng@0.0.0.0:37516] to [Up]
[21:05:54 INF] Connection was reset by the remote peer. Channel [[::ffff:127.0.0.1]:4053->[::ffff:127.0.0.1]:37517](Id=1293c63a)
[21:05:54 INF] Message AckIdleCheckTimer from akka://sng/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2Fsng%400.0.0.0%3A37516-1/endpointWriter to akka://sng/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2Fsng%400.0.0.0%3A37516-1/endpointWriter was not delivered. 1 dead letters encountered.
[21:05:55 INF] Message GossipStatus from akka://sng/system/cluster/core/daemon to akka://sng/deadLetters was not delivered. 2 dead letters encountered.
[21:05:55 INF] Message Heartbeat from akka://sng/system/cluster/core/daemon/heartbeatSender to akka://sng/deadLetters was not delivered. 3 dead letters encountered.
[21:05:56 INF] Message GossipStatus from akka://sng/system/cluster/core/daemon to akka://sng/deadLetters was not delivered. 4 dead letters encountered.
[21:05:56 INF] Message Heartbeat from akka://sng/system/cluster/core/daemon/heartbeatSender to akka://sng/deadLetters was not delivered. 5 dead letters encountered.
[21:05:57 INF] Message GossipStatus from akka://sng/system/cluster/core/daemon to akka://sng/deadLetters was not delivered. 6 dead letters encountered.
[21:05:57 INF] Message Heartbeat from akka://sng/system/cluster/core/daemon/heartbeatSender to akka://sng/deadLetters was not delivered. 7 dead letters encountered.
[21:05:58 INF] Message GossipStatus from akka://sng/system/cluster/core/daemon to akka://sng/deadLetters was not delivered. 8 dead letters encountered.
[21:05:58 INF] Message Heartbeat from akka://sng/system/cluster/core/daemon/heartbeatSender to akka://sng/deadLetters was not delivered. 9 dead letters encountered.
[21:05:59 WRN] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://sng@127.0.0.1:4053] - Marking node(s) as UNREACHABLE [Member(address = akka.tcp://sng@0.0.0.0:37516, Uid=1060233119 status = Up, role=[monitor], upNumber=2)]. Node roles [lighthouse]
[21:06:01 WRN] AssociationError [akka.tcp://sng@127.0.0.1:4053] -> akka.tcp://sng@0.0.0.0:37516: Error [Association failed with akka.tcp://sng@0.0.0.0:37516] []
[21:06:01 WRN] Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sng@0.0.0.0:37516]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: [Association failed with akka.tcp://sng@0.0.0.0:37516] Caused by: [System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Akka.Remote.Transport.InvalidAssociationException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it tcp://sng@0.0.0.0:37516
   at Akka.Remote.Transport.DotNetty.TcpTransport.<AssociateInternal>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Akka.Remote.Transport.DotNetty.DotNettyTransport.<Associate>d__22.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Akka.Remote.Transport.ProtocolStateActor.<>c.<InitializeFSM>b__11_54(Task`1 result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
---> (Inner Exception #0) Akka.Remote.Transport.InvalidAssociationException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it tcp://sng@0.0.0.0:37516
   at Akka.Remote.Transport.DotNetty.TcpTransport.<AssociateInternal>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Akka.Remote.Transport.DotNetty.DotNettyTransport.<Associate>d__22.MoveNext()<---
]
[21:06:04 INF] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://sng@127.0.0.1:4053] - Leader is auto-downing unreachable node [akka.tcp://sng@127.0.0.1:4053]
[21:06:04 INF] Marking unreachable node [akka.tcp://sng@0.0.0.0:37516] as [Down]
[21:06:05 INF] Leader is removing unreachable node [akka.tcp://sng@0.0.0.0:37516]
[21:06:05 WRN] Association to [akka.tcp://sng@0.0.0.0:37516] having UID [1060233119] is irrecoverably failed. UID is now quarantined and all messages to this UID will be delivered to dead letters. Remote actorsystem must be restarted to recover from this situation.
```

Working node logs:

```
[21:05:38 INF] Starting remoting
[21:05:38 INF] Remoting started; listening on addresses : [akka.tcp://sng@0.0.0.0:37516]
[21:05:38 INF] Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://sng@0.0.0.0:37516]
[21:05:38 INF] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://sng@0.0.0.0:37516] - Starting up...
[21:05:38 INF] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://sng@0.0.0.0:37516] - Started up successfully
[21:05:40 INF] Welcome from [akka.tcp://sng@127.0.0.1:4053]
[21:05:40 INF] Member is Up: Member(address = akka.tcp://sng@127.0.0.1:4053, Uid=439782041 status = Up, role=[lighthouse], upNumber=1)
[21:05:40 INF] Member is Up: Member(address = akka.tcp://sng@0.0.0.0:37516, Uid=1060233119 status = Up, role=[monitor], upNumber=2)
//shutdown logs are missing
```

2. Started and stopped COM node

Lighthouse logs:

```
[21:12:02 INF] Connection was reset by the remote peer. Channel [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:4053->[::ffff:127.0.0.1]:37546](Id=4ca91e15)
```

COM node logs:

```
[WARNING][18. 07. 2018 19:11:15][Thread 0001][ActorSystem(sng)] The type name for serializer 'hyperion' did not resolve to an actual Type: 'Akka.Serialization.HyperionSerializer, Akka.Serialization.Hyperion'
[WARNING][18. 07. 2018 19:11:15][Thread 0001][ActorSystem(sng)] Serialization binding to non existing serializer: 'hyperion'
[21:11:15 DBG] Logger log1-SerilogLogger [SerilogLogger] started
[21:11:15 DBG] StandardOutLogger being removed
[21:11:15 DBG] Default Loggers started
[21:11:15 INF] Starting remoting
[21:11:15 DBG] Starting prune timer for endpoint manager...
[21:11:15 INF] Remoting started; listening on addresses : [akka.tcp://sng@0.0.0.0:37543]
[21:11:15 INF] Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://sng@0.0.0.0:37543]
[21:11:15 INF] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://sng@0.0.0.0:37543] - Starting up...
[21:11:15 INF] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://sng@0.0.0.0:37543] - Started up successfully
[21:11:15 DBG] [Uninitialized] Received Akka.Cluster.InternalClusterAction+Subscribe
[21:11:15 DBG] [Uninitialized] Received Akka.Cluster.InternalClusterAction+Subscribe
[21:11:16 DBG] [Uninitialized] Received Akka.Cluster.InternalClusterAction+JoinSeedNodes
[21:11:16 DBG] [Uninitialized] Received Akka.Cluster.InternalClusterAction+Subscribe
[21:11:26 WRN] Couldn't join seed nodes after [2] attempts, will try again. seed-nodes=[akka.tcp://sng@127.0.0.1:4053]
[21:11:31 WRN] Couldn't join seed nodes after [3] attempts, will try again. seed-nodes=[akka.tcp://sng@127.0.0.1:4053]
[21:11:36 WRN] Couldn't join seed nodes after [4] attempts, will try again. seed-nodes=[akka.tcp://sng@127.0.0.1:4053]
[21:11:40 ERR] No response from remote. Handshake timed out or transport failure detector triggered.
[21:11:40 WRN] AssociationError [akka.tcp://sng@0.0.0.0:37543] -> akka.tcp://sng@127.0.0.1:4053: Error [Association failed with akka.tcp://sng@127.0.0.1:4053] []
[21:11:40 WRN] Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sng@127.0.0.1:4053]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: [Association failed with akka.tcp://sng@127.0.0.1:4053] Caused by: [Akka.Remote.Transport.AkkaProtocolException: No response from remote. Handshake timed out or transport failure detector triggered.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Akka.Remote.Transport.AkkaProtocolTransport.<Associate>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Akka.Remote.EndpointWriter.<AssociateAsync>d__23.MoveNext()]
[21:11:40 DBG] Disassociated [akka.tcp://sng@0.0.0.0:37543] -> akka.tcp://sng@127.0.0.1:4053
[21:11:40 INF] Message InitJoin from akka://sng/system/cluster/core/daemon/joinSeedNodeProcess-1 to akka://sng/deadLetters was not delivered. 1 dead letters encountered.
[21:11:40 INF] Message InitJoin from akka://sng/system/cluster/core/daemon/joinSeedNodeProcess-1 to akka://sng/deadLetters was not delivered. 2 dead letters encountered.
[21:11:40 INF] Message InitJoin from akka://sng/system/cluster/core/daemon/joinSeedNodeProcess-1 to akka://sng/deadLetters was not delivered. 3 dead letters encountered.
[21:11:40 INF] Message InitJoin from akka://sng/system/cluster/core/daemon/joinSeedNodeProcess-1 to akka://sng/deadLetters was not delivered. 4 dead letters encountered.
[21:11:40 INF] Message InitJoin from akka://sng/system/cluster/core/daemon/joinSeedNodeProcess-1 to akka://sng/deadLetters was not delivered. 5 dead letters encountered.
[21:11:40 INF] Message AckIdleCheckTimer from akka://sng/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2Fsng%40127.0.0.1%3A4053-1/endpointWriter to akka://sng/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2Fsng%40127.0.0.1%3A4053-1/endpointWriter was not delivered. 6 dead letters encountered.
[21:11:41 WRN] Couldn't join seed nodes after [5] attempts, will try again. seed-nodes=[akka.tcp://sng@127.0.0.1:4053]
[21:11:41 INF] Message InitJoin from akka://sng/system/cluster/core/daemon/joinSeedNodeProcess-1 to akka://sng/deadLetters was not delivered. 7 dead letters encountered.
[21:11:46 WRN] Couldn't join seed nodes after [6] attempts, will try again. seed-nodes=[akka.tcp://sng@127.0.0.1:4053]
[21:11:51 WRN] Couldn't join seed nodes after [7] attempts, will try again. seed-nodes=[akka.tcp://sng@127.0.0.1:4053]
```

Do you have any idea how to debug and/or resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see that the first thing I notice in the non-working node the hocon configuration contains different "seed-nodes" address from the working node.

IMHO the "seed-nodes" in all the applications [nodes as called in cluster] withinvthe cluster needs to be same. So in the non-working node instead of

```
seed-nodes = ["akka.tcp://songoulash@127.0.0.1:4053"]
```

replace with the below which is in the working node

```
seed-nodes = ["akka.tcp://sng@127.0.0.1:4053"]
```

Also, please check the github link for sample https://github.com/AJEETX/Akka.Cluster

and another link https://github.com/AJEETX/AkkaNet.Cluster.RoundRobinGroup

@Rok, Kindly let me know if this was helpful or I can further try to investigate.

Comment: Thank you for response. You have a good eye, but unfortunetly it was my typo in this post. All my configs have the same Actor System name. And connections (firewall wise) do happen because when I terminate COM node, lighthouse says "Connection was reset by the remote peer". There is one thing that I noticed. COM node is listening on port 37543 but lighthouse is connected on port 37546 to COM node. It could be something with that?

Comment: Another interesting thing. I downloaded all sources required for Akka (Akka, DotNetty,...) and after I replaced them with nugget I was joining cluster was successful. Well, I did upgrade frameworks (net45 -> net461 and netstandard1.6->netstandard2.0) for nuget consolidation purposes because I am having problem with loading assembly in COM environment..

Comment: @RokB, with the logs I was not able to figure out. May be if you 'd put the code somewhere like github . Then I shall try to reproduce and see.